# Using the comma as a list of things vs two related thoughts

Tags: commas

Recently I sent a mail wishing a friend well. I ended it with the following sentence.

> Please take care, and call me if you need anything.

The comma was included because the two were separate thoughts with the latter as an add-on to the former. Consider it without the comma.

> Please take care and call me if you need anything.

While grammatically correct, it sounds like a to-do list--please do the following things: (1) Take care, (2) Call me if you need anything.

Would you agree? I see this cropping up in a lot of writing here and there.

> I phoned my wife, and slept for 2 hours

seems to be a description of the list of things I did this afternoon, while

> I phoned my wife and slept for 2 hours

sounds like I'm reporting a very boring conversation.

Comment: In your example at the end, is there supposed to be a difference in the use of comma (or anything)? I don't see any.

Comment: "Please take care and call me if you need anything." is also subject to the (technically incorrect) interpretation of "Please take care *to* call me if you need anything."

Answer (score 2):

Structurally, there are two different ways to write things.

> I phoned my wife and slept for two hours

lists the two activities done in the form of *A and B*, while

> I phoned my wife, and I slept for two hours

joins two related complete sentences using an optional *joining comma* and *and* so that we do not write them separately.

I would not write

> *I phoned my wife, and slept for two hours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the use of the joining comma [(R L Trask's term)](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node11.html#SECTION00042000000000000000) need ever create ambiguity which cannot be resolved by the context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what's being asked here. As OP seems to realise, omitting the comma in these examples *may* imply the preceding and following elements are more closely connected.

Thus "I phoned my wife and slept for 2 hours" *could* (somewhat perversely) be taken to mean that the two actions were actually concurrent. Easily avoided by either including a comma, or (more fluently, IMHO) using *then* instead of *and*.

There is a general tendency going back over many decades to reduce punctuation. Arguably this leads to more contexts where such "unintended" conflation can occur in the mind of the reader.